# How to prove $\theta$ which $\in(0,1)$ is unique & $\theta$ is related with $x$ &$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\theta=1$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Show that

1. for any $x\gt 0$ there is a $θ=θ(x)\in(0,1)$ 
   satisfying
   $$
   \int_{0}^{x}e^{t^2}\,dt=xe^{\theta x^2}
   $$
   and
2. asymptotically, the parameter $θ$ satisfies  $\lim_{x\to+\infty}θ(x)=1$.

The problem is detailed.  
for question 1,you all have gave the answsers.
for question 2,there is a way prove$\lim_{x\to+\infty}θ(x)=1$:  

a hint:    
Second mean value theorem for integration.

Comment: Really you understand your own question?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_integration

Comment: It offers two conditions and too many things to prove...

Comment: Your question needs to be clearer. -1

Comment: Show first that for any continuous function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and any $x>0$ there is a $θ∈(0,1)$ with $\int_0^x f(t)\,dt=x\,f(θx)$.

Comment: @nayrb Thank you for your advice...

Comment: @LutzL Thank you,it's useful.

Comment: But it will only help for the first task, there is still some thought needed for $\lim_{x\to\infty}θ(x)=1$.

Comment: @user152441 LutzL's edit makes the problem so much more clearer. I had trouble understanding it before. Now it seems to me an interesting one. Downvote removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1): First note that since 
$$xe^{0x^2} = \int_0^x dt \leq \int_0^x e^{t^2} dt \leq \int_0^x e^{x^2} dt = xe^{x^2},$$
 by the Intermediate Value Theorem there is a theta such that $xe^{\theta x^2} = \int_0^x e^{t^2} dt$.

For (2): Consider the following. From (1) we can write.
$$e^{x^{2}\theta(x)}= \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}dt$$
Next we can split up the integral:
$$e^{x^{2}\theta(x)}=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{xc}e^{t^{2}}dt+\frac{1}{x}\int_{xc}^{x}e^{t^{2}}dt.$$
The first term is positive. The second term has the bound $(1-c) e^{x^{2}c^{2}} $ since $\int_a^b f(t)dt \geq (b-a)f(a)$ when $f$ is increasing. We can then write
$$e^{x^{2}\theta(x)} \geq (1-c) e^{x^{2}c^{2}}$$
or
$$e^{x^2(\theta(x)-c^2)} \geq 1-c.$$

If $\liminf_{x \to \infty} \theta(x) < 1$ then we can choose $c^2 < 1$ such that $\liminf_{x \to \infty} (\theta(x)-c^2) = -\delta < 0$. This would imply $\liminf_{x \to \infty} e^{x^2 (\theta(x)-c^2)}=0 \geq 1-c$, a contradiction.

Comment: Are you sure the limit is 1 in step (2)?

Comment: @user152441 No, I am not. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: It doesn't matter..

Comment: @user152441 I'd rather correct mathematics be associated with my handle than incorrect mathematics! I'm working on a different solution than the other answer's.

Comment: @user152441, I have a correct (hopefully) solution now.

Comment: ???I'm working on it too,but still get no point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14736/discussion-between-nayrb-and-user152441).

Comment: I thought your there are still some little bugs in your answer..c is depend on $\theta (x)$

Comment: A hint:Second mean value theorem for integration.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^2}dt = x\int_{0}^{1} e^{x^2 u^2}du,$$
hence the first point follows from the mean value theorem.
Moreover:
$$\theta^2 = \frac{1}{x^2}\log\left(\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2 u^2}du\right)\geq\frac{1}{x^2}\log\left(\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2(2u-1)} du\right)=\frac{1}{x^2}\log\frac{\sinh(x^2)}{x^2},$$
and the limit of the RHS when $x$ approaches $+\infty$ is clearly one.

Comment: The third line is not clear.?

Comment: It follows from the mean value theorem  $\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2 u^2}du = e^{x^2\theta^2}$, the inequality $u^2\geq 2u-1$ and the explicit computation of the last integral.